# Tomcat dbcp removeAbandoned issue

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat-dbcp

Can some one please explain me how to use removeAbandoned property properly?
The issue is, we have service method which runs in a transaction (applied @Transactional). The body can be some thing like 1000 select statements followed by 1000 inserts for example. The removeAbandoned property was set to 60 seconds. Now if 1000 insert statements execution time exceeds 60 seconds, it is throwing exception "Connection already closed" for the next db statement. Why is this happening and how to over come this? If i remove the removeAbandoned property every thing is working well. Here is my dbcp config.

```
db.initialSize=5
db.maxActive=150
db.minIdle=0
db.maxIdle=8
db.defaultAutoCommit=false
db.defaultTransactionIsolation=-1
db.maxWaitMillis=3000
db.timeBetweenEvictionRunMillis=1000
db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1000
db.testOnBorrow=true
db.testOnReturn=false
db.testWhileIdle=false
db.removeAbandoned=true
db.removeAbandonedTimeout=60
db.poolPreparedStatements=true
db.validationQuery=select 1
```

By using these properties, we are building a data source. Please correct me if i'm doing any thing wrong here. I'm assuming where ever this service is invoked, it opens a connection and executes db statements but it is trying to use the same connection after removeAbandonedTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of `removeAbondoned`, check [here](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/). You need to check your requirements and constraints and configure accordingly. If the execution takes that much time and this is the correct implementation then tune the configuration (increase the abandon timeout or remove it totally).

This might be common for nightly jobs and offline data migration processes for example. If there's a user interaction, I think you need to consider responsiveness, and hence change the implementation of the service. You might then need to separate it into different services or tune the SQL inside or remove some unnecessary calls, but keep configuration of the timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer yaccoub. Ours is also a job that runs in background. This is actually for dispatching emails in the background.

Comment: so I think you will need to remove the configuration as it tells the server to close any connection if it runs for more than a certain timeout ... if u think the answer is correct kindly accept it

Comment: Removing worked for me. But that affects the whole application. Then what is the need of removeAbandoned property. So i want to overcome this situation without removing that property. Just curious about the solution.

Comment: What about defining a separate data source for these long running jobs, with a separate persistence unit pointing to this data source and inject this persistence unit for the target methods ... This is a common practice used in the case of reporting queries - it's another use case but the strategy might be valid-

Comment: This is one is nice idea. I appreciate it. +1